# How to properly grant access to a database user in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, gcloud

I've been stuck with this problem for a couple of days.

I developed an application for appengine using Django and I'd like to use Google Cloud SQL for my database. Everything works fine until I want to apply migrations on the development server when it fails with the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'MY_DB_USER'@'MY_IP' (using password: YES)")
```

What I've done is as follows:

1. I followed the instructions in the [Django Support](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django) page to
   develop my application.
2. In order to create a 1st generation Cloud SQL instance I followed
   the steps outlined [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/getting-started), using the Cloud SDK.
3. I then created a new user following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/create-user) and assigned it a password.
4. I deployed the application using the following command line:

   gcloud preview app deploy MY-APP-DIR/app.yaml --version 0-1-0
5. I authorized my IP and my AppEngine Application ID. They are both listed in the ''Authorization'' section under ''Access Control'' in my SQL instance.
6. Finally, I tried to apply migrations using the following command line:

   SETTINGS_MODE='prod' MY-APP-DIR/manage.py migrate

**settings.py**

The relevant portion of my settings.py looks as follows:

```
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    DEBUG = False
    # Running on production App Engine, so use a Google Cloud SQL database.
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST' : '/cloudsql/[MY-PROYECT-ID]:[MY-CLOUD-SQL-INSTANCE]',
            'NAME': '[MY-DB-NAME]',
            'USER': 'root',
        }
    }
elif os.getenv('SETTINGS_MODE') == 'prod':
    DEBUG = False
    # Running in development, but want to access the Google Cloud SQL instance
    # in production.
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': '[MY-DB-NAME]', # db name. 
            'USER': '[MY-DB-USER]',
            'PASSWORD' : '[MY-DB-USER-PASSWORD]',
            'HOST' : '[IPV4 ASSIGNED IN GOOGLE CONSOLE]',
            'PORT': '3306',
        }
    }
else:
    # Running in development, so use a local MySQL database.
    DEBUG = True
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': '[MY-LOCAL-DB]',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': 'root',
        }
    }
```

Any idea as to what might be causing the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was the problem.

The proper way to grant a user database access, in order to apply migrations, is the following:

1. White list your IP. It should be shown under 'Authorized Networks'
2. Create a new database user account, but **do not** choose the 'Allow any host (%)' wildcard, **instead** select the "Restrict host by name, address, or address range" option and assign your IP ( The one you just whitelisted ).
3. You should now be able to run migrations with the command: `SETTINGS_MODE='prod' PROJECT_DIR/manage.py migrate`

As a side note, make sure the `root` user whose host is `localhost` **doesn't** have a password, else your App Engine application won't be able to connect to the database.

Hope this helps someone else!